# Why does this happen to the image when i use writablebitmap is it reading it wrong? do i need to have an offset?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, bitmap, writeablebitmap

I have been trying to load an image (which works) as a  bitmapimage then convert that writeablebitmap to grey scale by averaging all of the colours together how ever when ever i do it the image has green or blue and red line across seemly dependent if the offset was even or odd. I manged to change that so its white lines with weird messed up RGB across sections of the image. I dont know if its my code a common problem with writeablebitmap.

**images**

[this is what the image i am loading into the program looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEDeF.jpg)

[this is the image after i run my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr6qq.jpg)

**code**

```
void imageLoad()
        {

            BitmapImage bit = new BitmapImage();
            bit.BeginInit();

            bit.UriSource = new Uri(@"amazon.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
            bit.EndInit();


            storeinarray(bit);
        }

        void storeinarray(BitmapImage bit)
        {
            WriteableBitmap wrbit = new WriteableBitmap(bit);

            int pxWidth = wrbit.PixelWidth;
            int pxHeigth = wrbit.PixelHeight;
            int numColours = pxWidth * pxHeigth * 4;
            int[,][] colourData = new int[pxWidth, pxHeigth][];

            int stride =(bit.PixelWidth * bit.Format.BitsPerPixel+7) / 8;

            byte[] array = new byte[stride * bit.PixelHeight];


            bit.CopyPixels(array, stride, 0);


            for (int x = 0; x < pxWidth; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < pxHeigth*4; y+=4)
                {
                    colourData[x, y/4] = new int[4];
                    colourData[x, y/4][0] = array[x + y];
                    colourData[x, y/4][1] = array[x + y + 1];
                    colourData[x, y/4][2] = array[x + y + 2];
                    colourData[x, y/4][3] = array[x + y + 3];
                }
            }

            changeImage(colourData, bit, stride);
        }

        void changeImage(int[,][] colourdata, BitmapImage bit, int stride)
        {

            int avg = 0;
            WriteableBitmap writeable = new WriteableBitmap(bit);

            Int32Rect int32rect = new Int32Rect(x: 0, y: 0, width: writeable.PixelWidth, height: writeable.PixelHeight);

            byte[] dataforwr = new byte[stride * bit.PixelHeight];
            Random ran = new Random();
            for (int x = 0; x < colourdata.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < colourdata.GetLength(1); y++)
                {

                    avg = ((colourdata[x, y][0] + colourdata[x, y][1] + colourdata[x, y][2]) / 3);
                    colourdata[x, y][0] = colourdata[x, y][0];//B
                    colourdata[x, y][1] = colourdata[x, y][1];//G
                    colourdata[x, y][2] = colourdata[x, y][2]; //R
                    colourdata[x, y][3] = 255;//A



                }
            }

            int xs = 0;
            int ys = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataforwr.Length / 4; i += 4)
            {
                dataforwr[i] = (byte)colourdata[xs, ys][0];
                dataforwr[i + 1] = (byte)colourdata[xs, ys][1];
                dataforwr[i + 2] = (byte)colourdata[xs, ys][2];
                dataforwr[i + 3] = (byte)colourdata[xs, ys][3];

                ys++;
                if (ys + 1 == writeable.PixelHeight)
                {
                    xs++;
                    ys = 0;
                }


            }

            int buffersize = stride * writeable.PixelHeight;



            writeable.WritePixels(int32rect, dataforwr, stride, 0);



            Image iamge = new Image();
            iamge.Source = bit;

            Canvas.SetTop(iamge, 100);
            can.Children.Add(iamge);

            Image image = new Image();
            image.Source = writeable;

            // image.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;

            can.Children.Add(image);


        }
```

I have tried a solid block of colour for each pixel and all the pixel come out the same colour but then mix where there are green line and such e.g i set a solid colour red so A=255,R=255,B=0,G=0 the back ground would be red with yellow lines where the green and red have been put together

Comment: Why don't you simply create a FormatConvertedBitmap with e.g. PixelFormats.Gray16. You don't seem to need more than this single line of code: `image.Source = new FormatConvertedBitmap(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"amazon.jpg", UriKind.Relative)), PixelFormats.Gray16, null, 0d);`

Comment: this would work but i need to get the pixel data from each pixel and affect them by row. So making grey from the start works and if it cant turn the image grey ill struggle to affect the image in different way later on. thanks though that will save me code later on.